# Is there an heuristic for finding out the smallest height you can get when packing items in a tube?

Tags: algorithms, heuristics

It's sort of similar to bin packing, but instead of the minimum amount of bins,I was interested in just one infinite bin and finding out what's the smallest height you could get when you start packing items there.

I was thinking about this because of [RCPSP](https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/pstuckey/rcpsp/), in case anyone's interested. I already have an algorithm to solve it, but I'm curious about this one.

As this is related to an assignment of mine, please don't give me other intuitions. Thank you for your attention :)